# How to replace a specific character from a string given starting index

Tags: java

I am given a string  = `"SUBTOTAL(9,L7:L17)"`

I want to replace all **L** with **2** in given string but **L** from **SUBTOTAL** should not be changed or replacing all **L** with **2** inside brackets.

I have tried with `replaceAll()` in java method but its replacing all **L** with **2**
resulting `"SUBTOTA2(9,27:217)"` which is wrong

What i want like this
Result will be like : `"SUBTOTAL(9,27:217)"`

Comment: java String also has `replace()` which operates on first match only

Comment: @SharonBenAsher yes, but the first match is exactly the one that should NOT get replaced.

Comment: you need to find opening parenthesis by using `indexOf` and then search for `L` after that index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your string into two substrings based on the first occurence of `(`, then replace your character on the second part and recombine the result:

```
String string = "SUBTOTAL(9,L7:L17)";
int replaceStartIndex = string.indexOf('(');

System.out.println(string.substring(0, replaceStartIndex) 
  + string.substring(replaceStartIndex).replaceAll("L", "2"));
```

Outputs SUBTOTAL(9,27:217)